# Is it possible to remove video controls from an anchor?

Tags: javascript, html, css

On thumbnail click the video opens in a lightbox anchor. Is it possible to remove the options button (last button, 3 dots) from it? a picture: [video controls in anchor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDZfT.png)
my html:

```
<ul class="splide__list">
    <% videos.videos.forEach(function(video) { %>
    <li class="splide__slide">
        <a href="<%= video.href %>" data-lity>
        <img class="thumbnail" data-splide-lazy="<%= video.src %>" alt="<%= video.alt %>">
        </a>
        <p>
            <%= video.desc %>
        </p>
    </li>
    <% }) %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Googling the title of your post yielded [this](https://blog.addpipe.com/10-advanced-features-in-html5-video-player/#showingorhidingthevideoplayerscontrols) as the first search result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove those 3 dots you have to disable their functionalities.

You can remove it by adding these 2 attributes.
`controlsList="nodownload"` and `disablePictureInPicture`

```html
<video controls src="https://cdn.videvo.net/videvo_files/video/free/2019-12/small_watermarked/190915_B_02_HaLong_06_preview.webm" preload="none" disablePictureInPicture controlsList="nodownload"> </video>
```